# animate item while other has class JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

In this code snippet I was trying to make changes on absolute element for the menu item when it has active class, but the problem is when the class toggled and removed from current item the element still have the same effect and didn't enter the else statement.

As you see class active toggled between the menu items when click any of them and I use if this item has class active do this for the element. else back.
but else statement not working and keep the line under the menu item although it's not has active class anymore.

```js
$(function () {
  "use strict";
  var $menuItem = $('.nav li a'),
      $hr = $('hr');
  $menuItem.on('click', function (event) {
      $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).next($hr).animate({width : "100%"}, 200);
      } else {
        $(this).next($hr).animate({width : "0"}, 200);
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  
  });
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color:#222;
  padding:15px 10px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
.nav ul li {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  
}
.nav ul li a .active {
  color:red;
}
#home,#about,#services,#contact {
  height:600px;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:100px 0;
}
hr {
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
 height:2px;
 border:none;
    color: #ff0075;
 background-color:#ff0075;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
 z-index:-5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a><hr></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a><hr></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You add the class before your if statement so thats why you dont get into the else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added `active` class to current element, thus truthy section of `if` will execute.

You need to apply the animation on [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)ed element.

```
$menuItem.filter('.active').next('hr').animate({
  width: "100%"
}, 200);
$menuItem.filter(':not(.active)').next('hr').animate({
  width: "0"
}, 200);
```

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  var $menuItem = $('.nav li a');
  $menuItem.on('click', function(event) {
    $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $menuItem.filter('.active').next('hr').animate({
      width: "100%"
    }, 200);
    $menuItem.filter(':not(.active)').next('hr').animate({
      width: "0"
    }, 200);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav ul li a .active {
  color: red;
}

#home,
#about,
#services,
#contact {
  height: 600px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #ff0075;
  background-color: #ff0075;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      <hr>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      <hr>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
      <hr>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <hr>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```